# How to migrate from PHP 5.5.* to PHP 7.0.* and upgrade the entire LAMP stack on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS(64-bit) operating system?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, lamp, php7

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64-bit) operating system on my local machine.

I've already installed LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP) on my local machine.

Upon running following commands from the terminal I got the respective responses.

```
$ php -v

PHP 5.5.32-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Feb  5 2016 10:01:19) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

$ apachectl -V

Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:47
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Now as PHP7 has been released and other softwares too like http Apache server, MySQL, PHPMyAdmin which are part of my LAMP stack installation I want to upgrade them all to their respective latest stable version.

How should I make this?

I tried running following commands to upgrade all the software resources but these didn't get upgrade, I don't know why.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Someone please help me by providing step-by-step answer with necessary commands.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to stick to 12.04 when you're upgrading practically everything else that matters?

Comment: Upgrade to at least Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, or wait a couple of days and go directly to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

PHP7 has not yet been released as official Ubuntu package. If you are not in a hurry or you do not have too much time, I would just suggest that you wait for 16.04 which is due in April, and it will hopefully have PHP7 available.

You should, in the meanwhile, migrate from 12.04 to 14.04, so you are ready to update to 16.04 when it comes out. Direct migration from 12.04 to 16.04 will probably not be supported, as it has never been in the past.

If, on the other hand, you just want to try PHP7 now, you need to use Ondrej Sury's ppa. But I still believe that 12.04 is too old for that to work, and that you should upgrade first.

Look for a guide about that, you will find plenty of resources.

E.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Have fun.